# laravel-elixir - elixir.config.js not defined

Tags: laravel-elixir

I'm trying to add the reactify transformer to browserfy:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'reactify',
    options: {}
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.browserify('App.js');
});
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'browserify' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/carlo/Dev/jscomix/gulpfile.js:15:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:16)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
```

Seems that the config variable is not set. Can anyone see anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem, the issue was an old elixir version (2.0.0), it's working properly in version 3.0.0